# Analyzing equilibrium at origin of system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The system is $$x' = (2y+cx)(z+1)$$

$$y' = (-x+cy)(z+1)$$

$$z' = -z^3$$

For when $c = 0$, I want to show that the system is not asymptotically stable at the origin.

Since $z$ tends to $0$ as $t$ goes to $\infty$, I can approximate the system by assuming $z = 0$ (assuming $x$ and $y$ are eventually bounded).

I tried taking second derivatives to see that $$x'' = 2y' = -2x$$

and $$y'' = -x' = -2y$$
Then $ x = c_1\sin({\sqrt{2}t})-c_2\sin({\sqrt{2}t})$, and $y = c_3\sin({\sqrt{2}t})-c_4\sin({\sqrt{2}t})$.

This is not convergent unless we set $x=y=0$.
The question is two-fold:

(1). Is my reasoning valid?

(2).  I want to show that the system is stable with $c<0$ and $z(0)>-1$. But the same ideas I used above don't seem to work.

Comment: Just a small comment: $x''=-2x$ has general solution $x=c_1\cos(\sqrt{2}t)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{2}t)$ and not the exponential functions.

Comment: @mickep That is not a small comment! I'll have to see if my argument can be salvaged.

Comment: @mickep I think I fixed it-my previous argument showed that the equilibrium was not stable, which is not true. But my question largely remains.

Comment: Well, I don't even see you you go from your system to $x''=2y'=-2x$. But that is perhaps only me being slow.

Comment: @mickep I directly solved for $z$ to see that $z$ goes to $0$ as $t$ goes to $\infty$. Then I assumed that I could just let $z = 0$ and draw conclusions about the system, since $x$, $y$ would have to be bounded if they converge to $0$. Then I just differentiated both sides. I'm not sure if I can really do this, that is part of the question.

Comment: @Moo  I don't see where I would go from the z-substitution to determine the global dynamics of the system.